# Python: Pandas dataframe to call a value

Tags: python, dataframe

I convert json to Pandas dataframe and would like to call the value of "c".

```
>>> quote
{u'c': 89.77, u'h': 90.51, u'l': 89.32, u'o': 90.09, u'pc': 90.29, u't': 1591778794}
>>> quote = pd.DataFrame(quote.items())
>>> quote
    0             1
0   c  8.977000e+01
1   h  9.051000e+01
2   l  8.932000e+01
3   o  9.009000e+01
4  pc  9.029000e+01
5   t  1.591779e+09
```

I want the data for c. I currently used `quote.iloc[0][1]` but it is not robust.
What is the robust and elegant way to get the data for "c"?

Comment: `quote[quote['0'] == 'c']` should probably work. This way you can get the sub-dataframe where the value of column '0' is 'c' (regardless of its position).

Comment: It is not working as it cause keyerror 0

Comment: How about `quote[quote[0] == 'c']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `quote_items` and `wanted` such as

```
quote_items = {
    u'c': 89.77,
    u'h': 90.51,
    u'l': 89.32,
    u'o': 90.09,
    u'pc': 90.29,
    u't': 1591778794
}.items()

wanted = 'c'
```

What about simply [setting as index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the first column, i.e.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(quote_items).set_index(0)
>>> df.loc[wanted]
1    89.77
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Or even dealing with the [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to make things shorter

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(quote_items).set_index(0).T
>>> df[wanted]  # <=> df.loc[:, wanted]
1    89.77
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Otherwise, if you do not want to *locate* your data, what follows may be enough

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(quote_items)
>>> df[df[0]==wanted]
   0      1
0  c  89.77
```

less readable IMHO, and not ending with the same type of object ([`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) instead of [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) as previously)

---

But in the first place: is your input dictionary really representative of the data you have to deal with ? Depending on that, our answers may vary.